# Issue with input text box in Firefox when in a page containing Flash content

Tags: html, css, flash, firefox

I am pasting the most basic version of my HTML to demonstrate the issue:

```
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="myInputBox" id="myInputBoxID"/>
</form>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.michaelbechara.com/interiordesign.swf" style="margin: 0;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:-1">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.michaelbechara.com/interiordesign.swf" />
</object>
</body>
```

Here's the same thing in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BKNFG/

Basically, I have a text input and a flash content with some styling applied. While using this particular combination of CSS style on my flash content (100% width and height along with absolute positioning), I am facing a weird issue on the input box. This behaviour happens only in Firefox (I am using version 16.0.2).

> To reproduce the issue:
>
> - Place the focus/cursor in the input box and type a few characters
> - without taking the focus out of the box, again click inside the text-input box
> - Try entering further text

I am no longer able to type in any more text unless I move the focus out to something else and the focus back into the text input control.

I have tried using different other ways to embed the flash content including swfobject and variants of embed code. I believe this might be a bug in Firefox, but is there a solution by which I can get the text input working without having to the the focus out?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem with Firefox 19 alpha, maybe it's been fixed since? (I haven't tried 18 alpha or 17 beta.)

Comment: I just installed 17.0 beta and the issue is still there. BTW, I'm on Mac.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so maybe it's platform-specific...

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this on Firefox 20.0/MacOS 10.8.3. It appears to be a problem with plugins trapping focus (Firefox bug open since 2001(!) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78414). Only success I had was temporarily hiding the video while the text field was showing on top of it (say, temporarily replacing it with a placeholder image).